# How can I avoid the garbage?

Tags: c, arrays, string, file

```
strcpy(home,"");
    for(j=del1;j<del2;j++){
    home[ strlen(home) ] = word[j];

printf("your house is %s",home);
```

but I got garbage. I try to do this:

```
strcat(word[j],home);
```

but when I ran it it didn't work

I'm trying to make a simple program to write / read words from a file:

TO WRITTE:

```
fp = fopen ( "houses.txt", "a" );
fprintf(fp,"%s&",home);
fclose ( fp );
printf(" Inserted element\n");
```

TO READ:

```
char c, home[50],word[100];
strcpy(home,"");
int i=0,del1=0,del2=0,j;
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen ( "houses.txt", "r" );
while (c!=EOF)
{
    c=getc(fp);
    word[i]=c;

    i=i+1;
    if (c=='&')
    {
        del2=i-1;
        strcpy(home,"");
        for(j=del1;j<del2;j++)
        {
            strcat(word[i], home);// OR home[ strlen(home) ] = word[j];
        }
        del1=del2;

        printf("%s \n",home);
    }
}
fclose ( fp );
```

Comment: What are you even doing? What is home? And word?

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out.  Simple.

Comment: How is `home` declared?

Comment: it's an String 

char home[50];

Comment: You garbage values are probably due to undefined behaviour in `home[ strlen(home) ] = word[j];` you are over-writing on `\0` termination  then you can't use `house is %s",home);` , `%s` need nul-terminated string. Second, `strcat(word[j],home);` is complete wrong it should be `strcat(word + j, home);`  that is even not same as `home[ strlen(home) ] = word[j];`

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan I erased my answer, I just got the rep to comment (And I posted my answer at the same time as yours.

Comment: I think adding a home[ strlen(home) ] = '\0'; AFTER the for loop will make it work. Paste the full code please. I don't even know what word means. home might be running over it's allocated space.

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: @hawaii, by definition, `home[strlen(home)]` must already be `'\0'`.

Comment: @pat not in his case, as del2 might be the size of a string array named word. It can be copying all characters, except the final '\0'.

Comment: @hawaii `strlen(home)` returns the index of the first `'\0'` in `home`.

Comment: Yes, but like Grijesh said it is being overwritten on the loop.

Comment: there is all the code, I modified it

Comment: So if it's being overwritten, then how is `strlen` going to find it??  `strlen` is going to find some `'\0'`, possibly way off the end of the array (unless every byte in the whole memory is non-zero, in which case, you're likely to get a segmentation fault).

Comment: so if I decide to use: strcat(word[i], home);

i only want to concatenate a char to my home string, but is that incorrect?

Comment: `strcat` expects a `char*` as its first argument, but `word[i]` is presumably a `char`.  I still have no clue what it is you are actually trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Watch out : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/ `char * strcat ( char * destination, const char * source );` destination is first.

Comment: Are you just trying to print each of the `&` delimited strings in the file?

Comment: strcat won't work, because it will try to append a string, that is a sequence of char terminated by `\0`. Try someting like `int length=strlen(home);home[lengh]=word[i];home[length+1]='\0';`. home will still be a string after this operation.

Comment: So `strcpy(home, "")`, is just an expensive way of writing `home[0] = 0;`

Comment: Yes! Im trying to print delimited strings, I tried with lenght variable and I got garbage too

Comment: YES, That easy I have thhis example:

in houses.txt I have:

penthouse&littlehouse&bighouse

How can I get to those names?

Comment: Isn't there also an `&` after `bighouse` too?

Comment: yes it is, because I insert the name and a &

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is to print each of the `&` delimited strings in the file, then you should just read characters into a buffer until you find an `&`.  Then, replace the `&` with `\0`, print the buffer, and then reset the insertion point to the start of the buffer.  Something like this (note the lack of any error checking).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char home[50];
    int i, c;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen ("houses.txt", "r");

    i = 0;

    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (c == '&') {
            home[i] = '\0';
            puts(home);
            i = 0;
        }
        else {
            home[i++] = c;
        }
    }

    fclose ( fp );

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `fscanf` to hunt for the `&`'s for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char home[50];
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen ("houses.txt", "r");

    while (fscanf(fp, "%[^&]&", home) == 1) {
        puts(home);
    }

    fclose ( fp );

    return 0;
}
```